# retrieving React child component from Higher Order Component when testing Stateless Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing jest unit tests for a React Stateless Functional Component (SFC) that is inside a Higher Order Component (HOC). How do I use TestUtils to find a specific class in the SFC?

Specifically, my SFC/HOC looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import sizeMe from 'react-sizeme';

const MyClass = ({myText, size}) => {
  return (
    <div className="MyClassName">{myText}</div>
  );
};
export default sizeMe()(MyClass);
```

Here note that MyClass is a SFC and I am embedding it inside of the HOC sizeMe from the package [react-sizeme](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme).

The test I am trying to do is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import MyClass from './src/views/MyClass.js'
import Wrap from '../src/views/Wrap'

describe('<MyClass />, () => {
  it('can haz my text', () => {
    const myClass = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Wrap>
        <MyClass myText={'my text'} />
      </Wrap>
    );
    const myText = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(myClass,'MyClassName').innerHTML;
    expect(myText).toEqual('myText');
  });
});
```

In this test I am using the utitlity class Wrap that I would normally use to test SFCs:

```
import React from 'react';

class Wrap extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}
```

My test fails because TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass cannot find MyClass. I get the message "Did not find exactly one match (found: 0) for class:MyClass"

How can I retrieve MyClass? I would most prefer to use React's TestUtils, but I am open to other approaches if that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work, it is necessary export/import the non-HOCed component. This required 3 changes. First the export keyword should be added to the definition of MyComponent.

```
export const MyClass = ...
```

The second change is how MyClass is imported. Since the HOCed MyClass is the default export, exporting the non-HOCed version requires all exports from MyClass.js to be imported as

```
 import * as MC from './src/views/MyClass.js
```

Finally, the non-HOCed component can now be in the test as

```
<MC.MyClass myText={'my text'} />
```

Because the default export was not changed, the HOCed component will still be used in a regular import so no changes to the other parts of the application will be required.